# Azure - App insights availability - Web test - Reporting names are not shown rather URL is shown

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm currently running some webtest using Azure portal - Application insights availability.

In the webtest file, I have given reporting name for each request but those names are not shown in the availability report /graph rather it shows the request URL. What I should do if I want to see an name rather than seeing Urls?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of where you are expecting to get different names?

Comment: Please find attached screen shot

Comment: I don't think this functionality is available, however if you'd like to see it you can add to the [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights) or open an issue on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home)

Comment: ok.. have added an item to user voice

Comment: Great. You can campaign for it and help your item get more votes so that it gets more priority :)